# nginx iphone rewrite for angular app - getting 404 while refreshing

Tags: iphone, angularjs, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewrite-module

We have an angular app being hosted on nginx for mobile clients. All the routing is taken care of by the angular code. So there are no subdirectories etc. So the path is passed as an argument to the angular file which is "index_angular.html" and angular takes care of the rest. The sit works and navigation through the menu items work. But once i get into a menu item and then refresh the page, it returns a 404 error. Here's the nginx conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
root /apps/angular;
server_name angular.com;

location / {
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://angular.com';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS';
index  index.php;

if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry)') {

        rewrite ^/$ /index_angular.html last;

        }

}


location /menuitem1/ {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index_angular.html last;
}
```

I need to be able to refresh the page and have all the path arguments sent to the index_angular.html file which should take care of the routing. 
Kindly help.

Comment: Hi, I say this question is still open, could you find a solution for your problem ? Are you still working on it ?

Comment: Yes it is now resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure in your location on 404 to return index_angular.html

```
location /menuitem1/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index_angular.html =404;
}
```

This should work, let me know.

Here is a working exemple for me, case of I did wrong in your case :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name myProject.lab;

    root /var/www/myProject;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

}
```

### Update

I checked in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/web-server/), one alternative I guess is to define a redirect in case of error page :

```
location /old/path.html {
    error_page 404 =301 http:/example.com/new/path.html;
}
```

But I always use my first suggestion, and works well :)

Comment: A rewrite rule and "=404" wont work together i suppose.

Comment: Oops sorry, I thought it was a try_files :( ...  so if I understand well if /menuitem1/ so you redirect your users on mysite.com/index_angular.html ? What about keeping the URL and try_files index_angular.html :D

Comment: location /menuitem1 {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index_angular.html =404;
    }  ---- Trying this now.

Comment: Okay this seems to working fine. Can i have a catch all rule for all menuitems?

Comment: You need to use a regex on your location. It is an other issue but it should looks like location ~ ^/menu {} ... give a look at nginx documentation should be good : http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/web-server/

Comment: Is there a single regex for all location paths regardless of the name in nginx?

Comment: I don't know ... I think it could make sens to ask it as a new question, we start to be far from the original one.